# Transform Excel data into custom format

Tags: vba, excel, xslt, analysis

I'm attempting to transform a large Excel input table into a custom format, also as an Excel table. Visually this is what I need to accomplish:

[image]

The psuedo-code I've come up with to solve the problem goes as follows:

2. Pseudo code:

// Column A is of higher level than column B

```
Initialize dictionary
Read the entire spreadsheet into system memory 
    While(sheet has records) { 
        Loop through spreadsheet records top-down
        Start at cell A1 
        Look to the immediate right of column A 
            if(A:B not already in dictionary){  
            Dictionary>> Append B as child of A in dictionary // Must find correct entry and append value 
            }
        Move to cell A+1
        }
    Once sheet is out of records {
            Move one column to the right
            Repeat while method
            Do this until entire column is null
     }
     while (dictionary has records) {
       Key = Column A value
       List of values = Column B value
       Save values as new Excel sheet
     }
    end
```

I'm not sure if there are libraries that exist that would accomplish what I need here, I can use whatever language offers a solution.

Appreciate any input from you all.

Comment: I would loop through the data column-wise, left to right.

Answer (score 1):

Stuff the 'Raw Data' into a two dimensional variant array and cycle through each rank, building the children of the parent or sub-parent as the case may be.

```
Sub collate_family_values()
    Dim v As Long, w As Long, vVALs As Variant
    Dim sPAR As String, sTMP As String

    With ActiveSheet    '<-set this worksheet reference properly!
        .Columns("f:g").EntireColumn.Delete
        .Cells(1, 6) = "Output Data"
        .Cells(2, 6).Resize(1, 2) = .Cells(2, 1).Resize(1, 2).Value

        vVALs = Application.Transpose(.Range(.Cells(3, 1), .Cells(Rows.Count, 4).End(xlUp)).Value)

        For w = LBound(vVALs, 1) To UBound(vVALs, 1) - 1
            sTMP = ChrW(8203)
            sPAR = vVALs(w, LBound(vVALs, 2))
            For v = LBound(vVALs, 2) To UBound(vVALs, 2)
                If Not CBool(InStr(1, sTMP, ChrW(8203) & vVALs(w + 1, v) & ChrW(8203), vbTextCompare)) Then
                    sTMP = sTMP & vVALs(w + 1, v) & ChrW(8203)
                End If
                If sPAR <> vVALs(w, Application.Min(v + 1, UBound(vVALs, 2))) Or v = UBound(vVALs, 2) Then
                    .Cells(Rows.Count, 6).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).Resize(1, 2) = _
                      Array(sPAR, Replace(Mid(sTMP, 2, Len(sTMP) - 2), ChrW(8203), ", "))
                    sTMP = ChrW(8203)
                    If v < UBound(vVALs, 2) Then sPAR = vVALs(w, v + 1)
                End If
            Next v
        Next w
    End With
End Sub
```

I moved the 'Output Dat' results to the right of the 'Raw Data' due to an unknown number of rows to adjust for.

[image: variant array parse children]

Comment: Thanks so much for the solution. The final Macro needs to handle 10 columns with additional logic to handle NULL cells but after I fully understand the code I should be able to use this

Comment: I believe that all you should have to change is the range referenced within `Application.Transpose` and the location of the results data.

Comment: I've gotten that far, the problem is that the production data sometimes contains NULL cells so I need to:

Comment: I've gotten that far, the problem is that the production data sometimes contains NULL cells so I need to:
 - Check for the event of a NULL cell in the parent loop
- When a NULL parent is found, assign the new parent one level higher

I think this can be done in the bottom IF condition, here's some more sample data to visualize what I mean. 

[link](http://i.imgur.com/RVvAR2h.png)